# how to write double values in buffered image

Tags: java, bufferedimage, pixel

is there a possibility to write double twoD values in to buffered image without doing any type casting in Java ?? I have a twoD matrix with double values. I wish to write it as image but in Buffered Image only integer values can be written. finally I must be able to read those double values form that image. any ideas ?? help me out

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes you can. You need to create a custom `BufferedImage` backed by a `DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE` `SampleModel` and `DataBuffer`. Not sure how useful it is, but at least very doable. The `double` values will be directly accessible through the `DataBuffer`'s backing array.

Comment: thank for your help mr #haraldK. i will try this out

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but first you have to create a BuffuredImage with DataBuffer of type DataBufferDouble:

```
public static BufferedImage Double(int width, int height, int channel)
    {
    ColorSpace myColorSpace = new FloatCS(channel == 1 ? ColorSpace.TYPE_GRAY : ColorSpace.TYPE_RGB, channel) ;

    ColorModel myColorModel = new ComponentColorModel(myColorSpace,null,false,false,ColorModel.OPAQUE,DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE) ;

    return new BufferedImage(myColorModel, myColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height), false, null) ;
    }
```

Then you access the pixels using the Raster or directly with the DataBuffer, but not getRGB.

Comment: Thank you @FiReTiTi. could u please explain me how to use this on a image??

Comment: The code I just gave you is already an image. Then you can access the pixel values using the Raster ( mymimage.getRaster() ) with the getSample and setSample methods, or using the DataBuffer: double[] buffer = ((DataBufferDouble)my image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()